# Annotation processor not executed

Tags: java, maven, annotations

I am learning about annotation processor. I have created a following test project.

Project structure:

[image]

annotation MessageManager:

```
package annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MessageManager {
    public String messageBase() default "lang/res";
}
```

class MessageManagerProcessor:

```
package processor;

import annotation.MessageManager;
import com.google.auto.service.AutoService;

import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

@AutoService(MessageManagerProcessor.class)
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public class MessageManagerProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
        Set<String> annotations = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        annotations.add(MessageManager.class.getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println("im here");
        return annotations;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MessageManager.class)) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }

        try {
            File myObj = new File("filename.txt");
            if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("File created: " + myObj.getName());
            } else {
                System.out.println("File already exists.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("IM HEEEEEEERE");

        return false;
    }
}
```

MessageManagerImpl:

```
package test;

import annotation.MessageManager;

@MessageManager
public class MessageManagerImpl {
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMessageManager</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <generatedSourcesDirectory>${project.build.directory}
                        /generated-sources/</generatedSourcesDirectory>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessor>
                            processor.MessageManagerProcessor
                        </annotationProcessor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgument>
                        -proc:none
                    </compilerArgument>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-rc7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I am executing the project with `mvn clean install` but the annotation processor is not executed. Should I run the processor some other way? Also META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor contains path to my processor `processor.MessageManagerProcessor`

Comment: Not sure if I understand it correct, but this annotation will work during class call, and not at compile time i.e. `mvn clean install`. If I misunderstood, let me know. Also you can follow https://www.baeldung.com/java-custom-annotation for same.

Comment: So what should be changed to call annotation processor during compilation? My goal is to generate some code in classes annotated by @MessageManager

Comment: Change retention policy to `CLASS` or `SOURCE` depending on your need.

Comment: let me know if it helps or not.

Comment: Did I understood it right: you want to generate **some code in classes annotated** by `@MessageManager`? If so: this will not work at all!! Annotation processing as of now can create new source code (or other files), but it *cannot modify existing* source code.
Next: adding some print statements to the annotation processor should tell you what it is doing – if you do not have utilised a logging framework already to track the build process.

Comment: Then checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54281656/5255690 which describes how to use the annotation in Tests within same project.