# Netbeans+Maven+Annotations: Can't add annotation processor

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, annotations, annotation-processing

I am upgrading to Netbeans IDE 12.3.

I am using Maven (bundled) and Tomcat (installed).

I created a library that defines/implements annotations and an annotation processor.

I created a web application which uses the library, annotations, and annotation processor.

Under the old Netbeans IDE the annotation processor was declared in two place: as a processor under libraries and again as a processor class under compiling. It worked perfectly.

There is no such place under the new IDE:

How do I declare the annotation processor?

[image]

Here is the library POM:

[image]

Here is the updated library POM:

[image]

Comment: [1] I'm puzzled that you managed to use **Libraries** in the past, since that property has never been provided for Maven projects in NetBeans as far as I know. [2] I realize that you are not using Lombok as your annotation processor, but [this Lombok bug report details the POM configuration settings](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2325) under `<annotationProcessorPaths>` that are now required for Lombok to work, and maybe they apply in your case as well?

Comment: There are several NetBeans 12.3 tutorials on using annotation processors. They are absurdly out of date, and unlikely to be helpful, but just in case: [Annotation Processors Support in the NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/annotations.html)

Comment: I did not use Maven previously. So maybe this is an issue with Maven on Netbeans and not the new version of Netbeans.

Comment: Or maybe it not an issue with Maven or with NetBeans at all, but with the way you are using Maven. Can you update your question to show **pom.xml**? Perhaps you need to add some annotation processor information.

Comment: Normally you don't need to specify the annotation preprocessor in NetBeans with a maven project. NetBeans/Maven automatically evaluates when your processing library bundles the correct configuration file `services\javax.annotation.processing.Processor`.

Comment: services\javax.annotation.processing.Processor is new to me. I will research that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926255/maven-annotation-processing-processor-not-found

Comment: @EdIpser You posted a link without any additional comment. Did one of those answers solve your problem?

Comment: I think so. If I understand it correctly I need to switch to using Maven to declare the annotation processor instead of Netbeans. I'll post a confirmation when I get it working.

Comment: I am currently stuck trying to add the processors to the Maven POM file. I get a compile error: "Annotation processor 'bandung.processor.CommandProcessor' not found"

The class name is correct and in the library project. If I remove the annotationProcessor from the POM it compiles (but presumably doesn't declare the processor).

Comment: @EdIpser do you manage to resolve this problem ? i got the same problem when using lombok anotation in netbean, it's just not working out

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans does not provide a way to add annotation processor libraries and classes because they are, instead, declared in Maven.

I conflated two changes, upgrading my Netbeans and switching to Maven (since the new Netbeans does not support the old project structure).

I am still having difficulty with the Maven annotations but I think that's better addressed in a new question.

Thanks everyone for your help.